# How to change meta title as rich text

Tags: django-urls, wagtail

I am new to django. I want to change meta title(header) as rich text( or I want to remove html tag) in django wagtail dashboard,

I tried add `wagtailadmin/shared/header.html` file and change the title as {{title|safe}} but its not worked.

Comment: Consider posting the code you are working with. That makes giving answers so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I override templates/wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html
as 
{% block titletag %}{% blocktrans with title=page.get_admin_display_title|striptags page_type=content_type.model_class.get_verbose_name %}Editing {{ page_type }}: {{ title }}{% endblocktrans %}{% endblock %}

Now It fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to change the meta title to a rich text? Meta title is for your meta header.

Comment: I want to remove html tag in admin page title,
Now I fixed that. Thanks lot for help

I override templates/wagtailadmin/pages/edit.html
as 
{% block titletag %}{% blocktrans with title=page.get_admin_display_title|striptags page_type=content_type.model_class.get_verbose_name %}Editing {{ page_type }}: {{ title }}{% endblocktrans %}{% endblock %}

Now It fixed.